# I have created a small as3 game and I can't implement saving

Tags: actionscript-3, save

**Here is the game**
http://www.kongregate.com/games/austinkan/cookie-clicker-v0-1a

I need help to make the game at least save your total cookies so that when you reopen the game it keeps your score. The saving of what upgrades you have can be implemented once I grasp the concept of saving.

**Here is the code** *WARNING it is fairly large*

http://pastebin.com/9QgpddbT

Comment: Downvote: explain your problem, post the relevant code, explain your code and what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

[Saving and Loading in Actionscript 3 (Mini-Lesson)](http://as3gametuts.com/2012/02/28/actionscript-saving-and-loading-tutorial/) is a fairly good tutorial on how to do what you have asked.